# Xamarin forms app working as BLE server for communication with BLE client app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am going to make a server and client app using Bluetooth LE.
I was able to find similar projects for client apps.
But wasn't able to find any solutions regarding my server app .
The purpose of server app is to receive string message from the client and sends back a string as response.
The client app will send the message to the server app as it will get in the range of the server app Bluetooth.
Is there anyone who can help me with this?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I know nothing about this topic, but google does. https://android-doc.github.io/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServer.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Check out the Shiny library: https://shinylib.net/. It is open source and supports both BLE scenarios, host and client.